# boost::serialize: Struct with bit-field member variables

Tags: c++, winapi, boost, struct

I can't seem to figure out how to make this struct serializeable. It seems like you cant pass any of the members that have padding by reference, which from what I can tell through researching is just a reality of setting the padding. I tried the pragma pack statement but it didn't make a difference.

This struct:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214(v=vs.85).aspx

```
class SZ_DCB : DCB
{
private:
friend class boost::serialization::access;

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version){
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(DCBlength);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(BaudRate);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(fBinary);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(fParity);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(fOutxCtsFlow);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(fOutxDsrFlow);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(fDtrControl);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(fDsrSensitivity);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(fTXContinueOnXoff);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(fOutX);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(fInX);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(fErrorChar);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(fNull);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(fRtsControl);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(fAbortOnError);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(fDummy2);
      ar &  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(wReserved);
      ar &  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(XonLim);
      ar &  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(XoffLim);
      ar &  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(ByteSize);
      ar &  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Parity);
      ar &  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(StopBits);
      ar &  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(XonChar);
      ar &  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(XoffChar);
      ar &  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(ErrorChar);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(EofChar);
      ar &  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(EvtChar);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(wReserved1);
}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The "flag" bitfields (`fBinary`, `fParity`, etc.) are not serializable this way, because you can't take the address of, or make a reference to, a bit field.

In order to serialize them, you'll need to assign the values to local variables, serialize those, then save the (possibly modified) local value back into the bitfield.

Something like:

```
BYTE binary = fBinary;
ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(binary);
fBinary = binary;
```

(Using BYTE since fBinary is one bit.)

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know you could serialize arbitrary variables. I though you could only pass members and I though you had to serialize all of them.

Comment: I'd suggest using standard c++. `BYTE` is not c++

Comment: @sehe Since it's a windows header, with various windows typedefs including DWORD and BYTE, I opted to use BYTE.

Comment: BYTE is just a char as far as I know. the best solution I could think of was   `union{
  char binConf [32];
  DCB conf;
 };`   ...instead of inheriting from DCB, since it seems like you can use anything you want in the serialize member.